# What's the diff between VSS 6.0 and VSS 2005?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

We've been using VSS 6.0 since time began, but yesterday I nabbed VSS2005 off of our MSDN subscription, it wouldn't let me install it off the ISO through Daemon Tools (not sure why, but I submitted error report to MS...).  I noticed it had a program files directory right on the ISO, so I just copied the folder onto my hard drive.  Well, I opened up the client and behold, a glamorous version of VSS 6.0 connected to the exact same DB.

Anyone know if I'm going to destroy everything by using it?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you install VS2005 Service Pack 1, if you haven't already. VS2005 RTM has a *serious* bug in its analyze and repair utility which corrupts all databases it is run on. SP1 fixes that problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We moved from VSS6 to VSS2005 just over a year ago. The database structure is identical. The only caveat we found was if some people still used VSS6 on a database where others were using VSS2005. VSS2005 treats Unicode text files as text files, whereas VSS6 does not. Which means that when VSS2005 adds a Unicode text file, VSS6 sees it as binary (this affects csproj files among others).

Other than that, VSS2005 supports proper HTTP access to the database (provided server extensions are installed), improved LAN performance (again, with server extensions), and better file system dialogs (the nasty old ones are gone). However, the new file add dialog shows ALL files, not just the ones that aren't included.

Also, VSS2005 allows the provision of custom editors and differencing tools by file extension, which is very useful. For example, some of our XML files are encrypted, so we run a decryption tool before the difference tool by using this system, which has increased the efficiency of our review processes substantially.

There are also other tweaks here and there, mostly good but occasionally annoying.

Finally, nothing has been destroyed. In fact, there appears to have been less additional corruption in the database since the transition - but I wouldn't put this down to the new VSS as it wasn't a comprehensive test.

Comment: Good answer, especially since we're going to upgrade to use Delphi 2009 w/ unicode source files.

Comment: If you have the opportunity, I highly recommend moving to SVN or some other version control system as VSS is so damn flaky.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure, that there is no more danger of destroying anything than when using VSS 6.0.

It's quite a long time ago since I last used VSS, but we also updated from version 6 to version 2005. As far as I remember, there were only some cosmetic changes in the client (VSS explorer), but the format of the database and also the available feature were exactly the same than in VSS 6.

Comment: "no more danger than with vss6" isn't saying much.

Comment: The features aren't exactly the same, and I agree with Joel; VSS is still a terrible version control system.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine.

Since VSS just uses a file share for everything, and there's nothing that is really server based, you're fine. Not much has changed in the format of the database, mostly client side stuff.